# getting unexpected date when trying to convert string formed date into java.util.date

Tags: java, date, collections

I want to convert a string form date into a java.util.Date object.
I am able to convert but result is not as i am expecting.Here is the piece of code:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
String date = "1938-06-11";
java.util.Date utilDate = null;
try {
  utilDate = formatter.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("date:" + date);
System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
```

and the following output came after execution :

```
date:1938-06-11
utilDate:Tue Jan 11 00:06:00 IST 1938
```

please suggest me ,why this is happening, however the result should be

```
utilDate:Tue june 11 00:06:00 IST 1938
```

Comment: `mm` = minutes, try `MM` for months. I suspect the result should be `Tue Jun 11 00:00:00 IST 1938`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you specified the format to be yearyearyear-minuteminute-dayday.

If you check the api: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html you can see m stands for minute, M stands for Month.

**corrected**

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = "1938-06-11";
java.util.Date utilDate = null;
try {
  utilDate = formatter.parse(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("date:" + date);
System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
```

Comment: +1 I would use a Javadoc from Java 7 as Java 6 is about to be End Of Public Updates.